# how to call generic method with no parameters?

Tags: java, hibernate, generics

I need to write java generic method that gets no parameter and returns a `List`.
This generic method is used hibernate:

```
public <T> List list() {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    List result = session.createQuery("from " + T.class.getName()).list();
    return result;
}
```

I am tring to invoke this method. I tried the following but it creates compilation errors:

```
mgr.list<User>();
mgr.list()<User>;
mgr.list(<User>);
```

How can I call this method?

Comment: does the line: `List result = session.createQuery("from " + T.class.getName()).list();` also give you a compilation error?

Comment: @ggreiner: yes.. how do you know?.. it tells me "cannot select from type variable". I think this is something relatd to hibernate compile capabilities of my IDE. How can I make it pass ok?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe what you're trying to accomplish requires some refactoring. It looks like you're trying to create a generic Dao class that you can reuse to query any Model object. The problem is that without passing the class to the method, you can't get the type of the `<T>` generic at runtime.

One way to accomplish what you want is to create a base dao, which is extended by specific implementations that know the class they're dealing with at compile time.

```
public abstract class AbstractDao<T>{
  private Class<T> clazz;  
  public AbstractDao(Class<T> clazz){
     this.clazz = clazz;
  }


  public List<T> list() {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    List result = session.createQuery("from " + clazz.getName()).list();
    return (List<T>) result;
  }
}
```

Then extend the class:

```
class UserDao extends AbstractDao<User>{
   public UserDao(){
      super(User.class);
   }
}
```

Then call the method:

```
List<User> users = userDao.list();
```

Comment: The problam with this implementation is that I have to create instance of AbstractDao for eac entity type. Is there any way to create a non-generic dao but it's methods will be generic so I could instanciate the dao only once?

Comment: The only way to do that is to to modify the method signature of `list`, like this: `public <T> List<T> list(Class<T> clazz) {`

Comment: You should read this doc: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-genericdao/index.html

Answer (score 7):

You forgot this one:

```
mgr.<User>list()
```

Answer (score 1):

It may have something to do with "type erasure", because of using generics. When you call

```
T.class.getName()
```

that T type is erased before run time. It is not available at runtime, it is only used at compile time to make sure type safety. You probably need to write some code to get thy type of the persitence class at runtime, and then use that in mgr class. An exmaple is

```
public abstract class GenericHibernateDAO<T, ID extends Serializable>
        implements GenericDAO<T, ID> {

    private Class<T> persistentClass;
    private Session session;

    public GenericHibernateDAO() {
        this.persistentClass = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass()
                                .getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
     }

     // more methods


}
```

from https://community.jboss.org/wiki/GenericDataAccessObjects?_sscc=t

Here, it has persistentClass which is set to parameter type at construction time, then that persistentClass is in the class, whenever needed.